# How do I stop Outlook from updating Google Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar

I have exactly the same question that this poster on the Google forums asked (and didn't get answered) in 2012: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/gcYv0RTVhHM "How do I stop my work events (outlook) from showing up in my google calendar?"

I would love to use my primary Google calendar, but it's cluttered up with work meetings. I looked at it again after having given up on it long ago, and noticed that the meetings shown were outdated. So I purged the entire calendar. A few minutes later, the latest meeting added to the work calendar showed up on Google as well.

One bit of info that shouldn't mean anything: Years and years ago, I installed something on my work PC to update my Google Calendar with the Outlook calendar. But that software was discontinued, I've gotten at least one new PC since then, and I don't see anything installed that seems like it would behave that way.

So I don't see any way my work Outlook should be connected to my personal Google. And I don't see any way to turn it off. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) Check: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions -- See if there are online apps/services that are talking to Exchange Online and Google Calendar. Revoke access, clean your calendar and see if anything gets re-imported. 2) Is your Outlook using Office 365 (Exchange in the cloud). Could Exchange Online be talking to Google Calendar? In GC Settings > Settings > Other Calendars... Is there a subscription? Are these entries read-only or editable?

Comment: Sorry, neither of those seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Is your work Outlook using Exchange online or Google Apps as the host for your e-mail and calendar? Are you logging into Google with your personal e-mail or work e-mail?

Comment: No, it's a large corporation that doesn't use Google Apps. And I use the Outlook client application (version 14.0.6112.5000, FWIW). I use my personal email to log in to Google, but I did notice that I've set my work email as an "alternate address" at some point (though I can't find now where I saw that).

Comment: 1) You can also try resetting your Google Calendar by going to your person Calendar and look for "Reset Private URLs". That will set up a new private URL which should prevent forwarding the sync from Outlook to GC. 2) Remove e-mail from Google: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/76143?hl=en ... 3) Another possibility is you have a forwarding rule in Outlook that sent all calendar entries as an e-mail to Google Calendar.

Comment: Ok, I've done the "Reset Private URLs" and removed my work email from Google (except as a recovery email). I don't have a forwarding rule for calendar entries. I'll wipe the calendar again and see what happens. Here's an unrelated question, though: Why did someone vote down my question? Did I post it in an inappropriate forum?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21166/discussion-between-sunk818-and-robertb).